# on click add a-tag with href from textarea

Tags: jquery, click, href

i try since yesterday to get some code work, but i cant. My goal is: If i click on a button an "a-tag" should get wrapped around another div and the "href" from the a-tag should be taken from an input-field where a user can paste in a link f.e (somelink.html).

Here is what i got so far: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EdaWR/15/)

```
$("#linkgo").click(function () {    
    $("#wrapper").wrapInner("<a id='tablelink' href='#'></a>");            

    $('#link').change(function() {
      var newurl = $('#link').val();
      $('a#tablelink').attr('href', newurl);
    });
});
```

I paste a link the in the textarea, click on the button and a tag should be wrapped around the #wrapper with a href from the textarea. But nothing happens.

I hope i dont make a stupid mistake and maybe there is an better way to do this.

Comment: What does the web console say? And wrapping a `div` in an `a` is illegal.

Comment: I update my jsfiddle link. now its set the a-tag but without the href from the textarea. Its just for a intern project so no matter if its illegal ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#linkgo").one('click', function () {
        var a = $("<a />", {
            id: 'tablelink',
            href: $('#link').val()
        });
        $("#wrapper").wrapInner(a);    
    });
    $('#link').change(function() {
        var newurl = $('#link').val();
        $('a#tablelink').attr('href', newurl);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3673z/)

Comment: This works perfect. You can even paste another link und click again on the button and the script just change the href and dont add a completely new a-tag. Thats cool :)
Dont knwo why sombody gives you an "answer dont useful" :/

Comment: @Kuba may be because it generates an invalid html

Comment: @Kuba also there are crazys in SO

Comment: Yeah, maybe cause its invalid html. But maybe this is just for a test a not for public and commercial use. Cant understand that kind of people. Anyway. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?
http://jsfiddle.net/EdaWR/20/

```
$("#linkgo").click(function () {

    $("#wrapper").wrapInner("<a id='tablelink' href='" +$('#link').val() +"'></a>");    

    $('#link').keydown(function() {
        var newurl = $('#link').val();
        $('a#tablelink').attr('href', newurl);
    });
});
```

Comment: this works so far. but the solution from "Arun P Johny" is a little bit better, cause if you decide to change your link it just change the href and dont add a completely new a-tag ;) But of course if give you an "answer useful". Dont know why anybody givt you an "answer dont useful" :/